# SP13 Calendar - Editing Calendar Events at the Same Time

Tags: 2013, list, calendar

I created a calendar app in SP13 for multiple users to use.  The problem that's happening is that they sometimes edit the same event at the same time.

Is there a way to avoid end-users from editing an calendar event at a same time?

Answer (score 1):

The only out of the box option in this scenario is enabling Content Approval.

List Settings -> Versioning Settings -> Require Content Approval for submitted items

Once this is enabled You can choose who can see the draft versions.

Finally only approved version will get listed in the calendar.

*In case of document library we have another option of `Forced checkouts` but unfortunately its not available for list items (calendar event is a list item)*

Comment: Thank you for your help!  What would be option if it's not an out of box?

Comment: You should create a custom edit form - Before editing starts store the values in memory - On save compare the initial value with what is available in the list(to check if someone else has updated or not)